# Game Center unauthenticated, request authentication in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

Swift 4, iOS 12.

Using Game Center to record high scores in a game. Everything works, assuming the user is logged into Game Center. I can detect when they haven't but cannot quite figure out how to switch Game Center on if that is the case.

```
func ask4GameCenter() {
    let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: "Log into Game Center to record High Scores", preferredStyle: .alert)

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ignore", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.gameOn()
    }))
    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Logon", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "gamecenter:")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
            if success {
                self.gameOn()
            }
        })
    }))
    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer.

```
func ask4GameCenter() {
    let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: "Log into Game Center to record High Scores", preferredStyle: .alert)

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ignore", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.gameOn()
    }))
    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Logon", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }
        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
            if success {
                self.gameOn()
            }
        })
    }))
    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```